# How to set text over image?

Tags: css

How can i add text over image ? I always get text bellow image? Is there any style so that title and descripton goes over image and not below?

```
  <div class="row">
        @foreach (var banner in Model.SportBanners)
        {

       <a href="@banner.LinkTo">
       <img id="resize" src="@banner.BannerPath" alt="" />
       <div class="@banner.ClassTag">

        </div>
        </a>
       <div class="image" style="">
        <h1>
        @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(banner.Title).Replace("-", "<br />"))
     </h1>
      <br>
    <p> @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.Encode(banner.Description).Replace("-", "<br />"))</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
    }
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes there is a, perhaps you should read about `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` for your images, then use CSS to position the figcation

Comment: I think if you use css to set your image as a background-image to the tag with the text in it.

Comment: Please demonstrate with an example of the **output HTML** and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positioning.

Set the `position: relative` of the containing element.

Set the `position: absolute` of any internal element that you want to take control over beyond the default behaviour. Then `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` will allow you to position this element wherever you want in the containing div.

This will help you position things based on your HTML where `img` tags are used (allowing CMS driven alts etc.), rather than setting them as background images, which will require verbose classes or inline style tags.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/5nryk3L6/2/ for a simplified version (removes the CMS backend stuff) of your code that achieves this. I've added a margin-left on the container to demonstrate how position absolute values are relative to the next element up the DOM tree with position relative set, as this can be quite confusing